# Convert input's NewLines to <br /> tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net

I have implemented a code, which works like this:-

On Click of enter it generates `<br />` tag. I want that it should generates the `<br />` I want, whenever user click on enter it should generate the `<br />` tag but at the same time it should not be visible.Please find the code for your reference:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function EnterEventDesc(e) {
       if (e.keyCode == 13) {
           var input = $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtJobDesc");
           input.val(input.val() + "<br/>");
           return false;
       } else {
           return true;
       }

   }
 </script>
```

The `<br />` tag is coming but I want to hide it at the same time. Please help

Comment: Is your input a textarea or text input?

Comment: It looks like your input is a text field or textarea. You can't hide *anything* inside those controls. It also looks like using an off-the-shelf WYSIWUG editor instead of custom code might be worth it.

Comment: Without using a hidden input element, you can't do that. Why not use a `<textarea>` element, and then convert newlines to breaks on the server side?

Comment: Why would you first insert a `br` and then hide it? Don't insert it at all, if you don't want a linebreak…

Comment: @Jon: can you share some things related to WYSIWYG ?

Comment: @BenM: can you share some links to achieve that ?

Comment: @feeela: How ? i need whenever there is two paragraph, it should have a gap between both. As it is not taking in front end repeater

Comment: @Shrutika: No, but Google can.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are using ASP.Net and you are trying to convert Input's NewLines to `<br />` tag in order to use somewhere else like save in Database.
If it's true you are in a wrong way, let the user to create new lines in the textarea using Enter Key, remove js code totally and then in codebehind use this function:

**C#:**

```
public static string LineBreaksTextToDB(string input)
{
    return System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(input, "([^\\r])[\\n]", "$1\\r\\n").Replace("\\r\\n", "<br />");
}
```

**VB.NET:**

```
Public Shared Function LineBreaksTextToDB(ByVal input As String) As String
    Return System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(input, "([^\r])[\n]", "$1\r\n").Replace("\r\n", "<br />")
End Function
```

Then do something like this:

```
... = LineBreaksTextToDB(txtMyInput.Text)
```

and all NewLines are converted to `<br />` tags.

**Update:**

If you want to call back this saved data in an Input, so you need to convert `<br />` to NewLine again. But if you try to show data in something like a `Lable` you don't need to do anything because `<br />` tags are implemented in HTML automatically.

**C#:**

```
public static string LineBreaksDBToText(string input)
{
    return input.Replace("<br />", System.Environment.NewLine);
}
```

**VB.NET:**

```
Public Shared Function LineBreaksDBToText(ByVal input As String) As String
    Return input.Replace("<br />", vbCrLf)
End Function
```

Then do something like this:

```
txtMyInput.Text = LineBreaksDBToText(myDatabaseTable.myField)
```

and all `<br />` tags are converted to NewLines.

Note: I'm not sure about C# it's just conveted VB code using [This Convertor](http://codeconverter.sharpdevelop.net/SnippetConverter.aspx).

Comment: can you do it in C# for me

Comment: @Shrutika: Check the updated answer and let me know the result.

Comment: ... = LineBreaksTextToDB(txtMyInput.Text) here ... means exavtly what needs to be done ?

Comment: @Shrutika: Assume you want to save `txtMyInput.Text` in database, if you do it normally you miss new lines in database but if you use `LineBreaksTextToDB(txtMyInput.Text)` all new lines is converted to `<br />` and saved in database.

Comment: yes i want to save that description in DB. and from there I have to show that in a repeater in front end. I am able to get <br /> tag.but couldn't make that tag invisible

Comment: Do you want to show this saved value in a `Lable` or in an `Input` again (in your repeater)?

Comment: @Shrutika: Check the updated answer and let me know that has your problem been solved or not.

Comment: where to add this line ? txtMyInput.Text = LineBreaksDBToText(myDatabaseTable.myField) on page load ?
And also, will it directly take myDatabaseTable.myField as a parameter ?

Comment: It seem you have another problem else that mentioned in your question, you say that you want to load database texts in a repeater in a `TextArea` input, well, how do you do it before? are you assign the database value to this `TextArea`? if yes so before assign value, call `LineBreaksDBToText` and then put value in `TextArea` then all `<br />` tags in your database are converted to NewLines in `TextArea`. and about second question: i think  it will directly take as a parameter but if don't, so convert in to `String` before that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a new line, you can insert `"\n"` instead of `<br>`

Comment: My issue is to make invisible the <br /> tag from the textarea. how to achieve that ?

Comment: What do you mean by "making them invisible" ? You want them in the source code but not displayed ? What's your final purpose?

Comment: When I click on enter a <br/> tag comes in the textarea, I want to hide that tag

Comment: Remove all your javascript code and that will hide the <br> tag .

Answer (score 0):

If you use a `textarea` you have plain text and do not need `<br>`'s.

Convert the plain text line breaks `\n` to `<br>` on the backend.

Alternatively, when using an HTML replacement for the textarea (a WYSIWYG editor), you could set the line break behavior via CSS.

```
#myEditorBox {
    white-space: pre;
}
```